# Bind v-model of textarea to array in Vue.js in v-for loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I want to bind an array to a *textarea* where each line in this *textarea* is one element in the array. I have no idea how to solve that. I already tried using a `v-:change` method combined with a temporary `v-model` to update, but that's pretty dirty.

For example:

```
<div v-for="item, index in list">
<b-form-textarea v-model.trim="list[index]"></b-form-textarea>
</div>
```

Result should look like:

```
list[0] = ['row1 of textarea 1', 'row 2 of textarea 1', ...]
list[1] = ['row1 of textarea 2', 'row 2 of textarea 2', ...]
```

Comment: You could only bind the whole textarea content to a data property using v-model, you could use computed property to update the textarea from your list and watch property to update the list from the textarea content

Comment: yes, I have to say I am pretty new to vue.js but I found an approach using computed property with getter and setter. But I didn't manage to use this together with v-for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could save the input value of each textarea in an object, which are collected in an array.

This array could be processed via a computed property to get your desired structure - `split("\n")` in your case.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    list: [{
        id: 1,
        value: ""
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        value: ""
      },
    ]
  },
  computed: {
    listByBreaks() {
      return this.list.map(e => {
        return e.value.split("\n");
      });
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
<!-- Required Stylesheets -->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" />

<!-- Required scripts -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-polyfill@latest/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <div v-for="item in list" :key="item.id">
    <b-form-textarea v-model="item.value"></b-form-textarea>
    <br/>
  </div>
  List by breaks: {{ listByBreaks }}
</div>
```